# Фильтрация списка объектов по уникальным значениям

Tags: c#, list, фильтрация

Все привет, столкнулся с проблемой фильтрации списка по уникальным значениям.
Есть структура

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string Name;
    public string City;
    public string Division;
}
```

Нужно вытащить из `List<MyStruct>` уникальные значения. Причем уникальным считается значение, где хотя бы одно поле из трех чем-то отличается

Comment: Ну я бы описал компараторы, а потом через `linq` взял `.Distinct()`

Comment: @CrazyElf для структур `Equals` по умолчанию и так проверяет равенство всех полей.

Comment: @MaxS Я что-то такое смутно помнил, но не был уверен )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `ValueType` (от которого неявно наследуются все пользовательские структуры) переопределен метод [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals?view=net-6.0#system-valuetype-equals(system-object)), который по умолчанию сравнивает инстансы структур по равенству полей в отличие от классов, где по умолчанию вызывается `ReferenceEquals` (сравнение ссылок на объекты).

Это позволяет вам использовать любые конструкции, явно или неявно вызывающие сравнение экземпляров через `Equals`, и получать *ожидаемое* поведение. Например, вы можете решить вашу задачу через [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) и его метод `Distinct` (который под капотом вызывает `Equals`) в одну строчку кода:

```
var list = new List<MyStruct>() { /* инициализация */ };
var result = list.Distinct(); // результат в виде IEnumerable<MyStruct>
var resultList = result.ToList(); // при необходимости, можно привести к List<MyStruct>
```

Обратите внимание: [переопределение `Equals`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs,25) для структур *может* использовать быструю проверку равенства структур через побитовую проверку, но только в некоторых случаях, а именно (сведения неполные, на самом деле структура ещё должна быть "tightly packed", подробнее [здесь](https://medium.com/@semuserable/c-journey-into-struct-equality-comparison-deep-dive-9693f74562f1)):

> 1. Тип значения содержит только поля простых типов и не переопределяет
>    метод Equals.
> 2. Тип значения содержит только поля типов значений, для которых
>    выполняется условие (1) и не переопределяет метод Equals.
> 3. Тип значения содержит только поля типов значений, для которых
>    выполняется условие (2) и не переопределяет метод Equals.

Если быстрая проверка равенства экземпляров не может быть проведена, равенство будет устанавливаться поочерёдным сравнением полей с использованием [рефлексии](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection), что является дорогой по времени операцией. Если быстродействие критично для вас на этом участке кода, вы можете реализовать интерфейс `IEquatable<MyStruct>` для своей структуры (*желательно*) и (или) переопределить метод `Equals` и тогда уже и `GetHashCode` самостоятельно. Также можно переопределить эти методы, если вам нужно реализовать какую-то свою логику сравнения (например, считать, что экземпляры структуры равны, если равны поля `Name` и `City`, а на `Division` не обращать внимания).

Comment: Спасибо больше, даже не думал, что list.Distinct(); можно применить ко всей структуре, а не к каждому полю отдельно, я уже начал реализовывать способ с объединением всех полей в одну строку и сравнением их со списком уникальных значений

Comment: Объединять все поля в одну строку точно не нужно, т.к. это очень дорогая операция и по времени и по памяти. Если хотите свою логику сравнения - реализуйте `IEquatable<MyStruct>` и определите метод `Equals` как вам нужно, например так: `public bool Equals(MyStruct other) => Name == other.Name && City == other.City && Division == other.Division;`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Для заданного условия уникальности нужно соединить строки структуры в одну, и использовать её для проверки уникальности всей структуры.
2. Уникальные значения выявить просто. Нужно сделать массив повторов (bool) такого же размера. Пройтись по всему списку циклом. В начале цикла проверить признак повтора, если он ложь, то вывести элемент как уникальный и пройтись вложенным циклом по оставшимся до конца элементам списка: сравнить текущий элемент из вневнего цикла с текущим из вложенного, если равны, то поставить признак повтора для текущего вложенного в истину.

Сделал тестовую программу:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace BankRobbery{
    public struct MyStruct{
        public string Name;
        public string City;
        public string Division;
        public MyStruct(string[] n, string[] c, string[] d, Random r){
            Name = n[r.Next(n.Length)];
            City = c[r.Next(c.Length)];
            Division = d[r.Next(d.Length)];
        }
        public static bool operator == (MyStruct ms1, MyStruct ms2){
            return String.Concat(ms1.Name, ms1. City, ms1.Division) == String.Concat(ms2.Name, ms2. City, ms2.Division);
        }
        public static bool operator != (MyStruct ms1, MyStruct ms2){
            return String.Concat(ms1.Name, ms1. City, ms1.Division) != String.Concat(ms2.Name, ms2. City, ms2.Division);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() {return base.GetHashCode();}
        public override bool Equals(object ms) {return base.Equals((MyStruct)ms);}
    }
    class ClippyNMerlin{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            var N = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
            var Names = File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt"); // 64 entries
            var Cities = File.ReadAllLines("Cities.txt"); // 39 entries
            var Divisions = File.ReadAllLines("Divisions.txt"); // 7 entries
            var Rand = new Random();
            var MyList = new List<MyStruct>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) MyList.Add(new MyStruct(Names, Cities, Divisions, Rand));
            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start(); var MyResult = MyList.Distinct().Count(); watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count by List.Distinct {0}", MyResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            var MyArray = MyList.ToArray();
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            var r = new bool[N]; MyResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (!r[j]) {MyResult++; for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) if (!r[k]) r[k] = MyArray[j].Equals(MyArray[k]);}  
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count by Equals {0}", MyResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            r = new bool[N]; MyResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (!r[j]) {MyResult++; for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) if (!r[k]) r[k] = MyArray[j] == MyArray[k];}  
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count by fields concatenation {0}", MyResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start(); // потерянный код :-(
            r = new bool[N]; MyResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (!r[j]) {MyResult++; for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
                    if (!r[k]) r[k] = MyArray[j].Name == MyArray[k].Name && MyArray[j].City == MyArray[k].City
                        && MyArray[j].Division == MyArray[k].Division;}  
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count by fields comparison  {0}", MyResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Результаты на списке из 10000 элементов:

Count by List.Distinct 7638

Elapsed time 0,164

Count by Equals 7638

Elapsed time 7,184

Count by fields concatenation 7638

Elapsed time 1,921

Count by fields comparison  7638

Elapsed time 1,921

Вот и посмотри теперь, что даёт наихудший результат.

И что интересно (закономерно, конечно), если сделать больше повторов (32 имени вместо 64), то Distinct работет медленнее, а остальные методы быстрее. Но как, скажите, сделан Distinct, если он работает быстрее всех? Возможно, он использует быструю сортировку?

Потерялся сброс и пуск таймера перед последним тестом. Вот результаты:

Count by List.Distinct 5889

Elapsed time 0,239

Count by Equals 5889

Elapsed time 5,38

Count by fields concatenation 5889

Elapsed time 1,592

Count by fields comparison  5889

Elapsed time 0,223

Теперь всё выглядит очень логично.

Под руководством @MaxS довёл до ума:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace DistinctTestTask{
    public struct MyStruct{
        public string Name;
        public string City;
        public string Division;
        public MyStruct(string[] n, string[] c, string[] d, Random r){
            Name = n[r.Next(n.Length)];
            City = c[r.Next(c.Length)];
            Division = d[r.Next(d.Length)];
        }
        public static bool operator == (MyStruct ms1, MyStruct ms2){
            return String.Concat(ms1.Name, ms1. City, ms1.Division) == String.Concat(ms2.Name, ms2. City, ms2.Division);}
        public static bool operator != (MyStruct ms1, MyStruct ms2){
            return String.Concat(ms1.Name, ms1. City, ms1.Division) != String.Concat(ms2.Name, ms2. City, ms2.Division);}
        public bool Equals(MyStruct other){ return Name == other.Name && City == other.City && Division == other.Division;}
        public override int GetHashCode(){ return ((Name.GetHashCode() * 31) ^ City.GetHashCode() * 31) ^ Division.GetHashCode();}
    }
    class DistinctTest{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            var N = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
            var Names = File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt");
            var Cities = File.ReadAllLines("Cities.txt");
            var Divisions = File.ReadAllLines("Divisions.txt");
            var Rand = new Random();
            var MyList = new List<MyStruct>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) MyList.Add(new MyStruct(Names, Cities, Divisions, Rand));
            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start(); var MyResult = MyList.Distinct().Count(); watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}, elapsed time {1} by List.Distinct\r\n", MyResult, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            var MyArray = MyList.ToArray();
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            var r = new bool[N]; MyResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (!r[j]) {MyResult++; for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) if (!r[k]) r[k] = MyArray[j].Equals(MyArray[k]);}  
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}, elapsed time {1} by Equals\r\n", MyResult, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            r = new bool[N]; MyResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (!r[j]) {MyResult++; for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) if (!r[k]) r[k] = MyArray[j] == MyArray[k];}  
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}, elapsed time {1} by fields concatenation\r\n", MyResult, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            r = new bool[N]; MyResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (!r[j]) {MyResult++; for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
                    if (!r[k]){ var maj = MyArray[j]; var mak = MyArray[k];
                        r[k] = maj.Name == mak.Name && maj.City == mak.City
                        && maj.Division == mak.Division;}}  
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}, elapsed time {1} by fields comparison\r\n", MyResult, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            var set = new HashSet<MyStruct>();
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) set.Add(MyArray[j]);  
            MyResult = set.Count; watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}, elapsed time {1} by hash code\r\n", MyResult, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Результаты:

Count 5972, elapsed time 0,01 by List.Distinct

Count 5972, elapsed time 0,217 by Equals

Count 5972, elapsed time 1,448 by fields concatenation

Count 5972, elapsed time 0,225 by fields comparison

Count 5972, elapsed time 0,012 by hash code

Вот теперь это правильно демонстрирует работу различных алгоритмов.

**Вывод:** Использование хэша, уникального в пределах не менее количества объектов, позволяет упорядочить коллекцию объектов и, таким образом, проверить уникальность объектов без попарного сравнения.

Comment: Соединение строк в одну - дорогая и совершенно не нужная здесь операция.

Comment: Конечно, можно обойтись и без неё, выполнив три сравнения и две логические операции. Для оптимизации я бы начинал сравнение с Name, там должно быть больше уникальных значений, если предположить, что наличие полей City и Division говорит о том, что эта информация об одной компании, и количество локаций и подразделений не должно быть сколько-нибудь большим.

Comment: Если не брать в расчёт оптимальность, можно сделать изящное решение с помощью методов агрегирования данных.

Comment: Способ тоже рабочий, именно к нему я и пришел, пока думал, но способ выше гораздо дешевле обходится, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @MaxS "дорогая и совершенно не нужная здесь операция" - оказывается, это далеко не так, см. пример

Comment: @rotabor Вы что-то не так делаете. Во-первых, так замеры не проводят. Сначала делается "прогревочный" запуск профилируемого кода, затем n-ое количество тестовых итераций с вычислением среднего значения (иногда считают ещё и дисперсию, но это ладно). Во-вторых, вы немного нечестно поступаете с замером для Distinct, добавляя туда ещё и `Count()` у которого время выполнения в общем случае O(n) как бы, а не константа. Но даже это всё некритично.

Comment: @rotabor А что критично: 1. Вы не перезапускаете таймер перед последним тестом (Count by fields comparison). Если вы это сделаете, то увидите, что этот метод поиска работает ОЧЕНЬ быстро (но не быстрее Distinct, который под капотом использует `HastSet<T>`).

Comment: @rotabor 2. Зачем вы пишете ненужную перегрузку методов `Equals` и `GetHashCode`, которые просто вызывают свои базовые реализации? Это бессмысленно. Но важно другое: вы используете именно метод `Equals(object)`, что в случае со структурами приводит к дорогим операциям boxing/unboxing и очень дорогой рефлексии в базовой реализации для структур. Из-за этого такое плохое время. Реализуйте интерфейс `IEquatable<MyStruct>` и определите метод `bool Equals(MyStruct other) => Name == other.Name && City == other.City && Division == other.Division;`. Теперь конкатенация строк сильно проигрывает Equals.

Comment: @rotabor "Count by fields comparison" впрочем всё равно будет выигрывать у Equals, т.к. сравнение происходит "на месте" в коде без передачи экземпляра структуры в метод `Equals` (которые передаются копированием, а не по ссылке в отличие от классов, что тоже немного дорого для тех структур, которые структурами быть вообще-то и не должны). Наконец, реализовав `IEquatable<MyStruct>` посмотрите теперь на время работы `Distinct`, сильно удивитесь, и окончательно забудьте про все эти ненужные танцы с бубном. `HashSet<T>` тоже под капотом использует ваш новый `Equals(MyStruct)` без boxing/reflection.

Comment: @rotabor Нужно ещё больше оптимизации – переопределите `GetHashCode()` (именно реализуйте переопределение, а не просто вызовите метод базового класса), он также используется для работы `HashSet<T>` (и даже "первее", чем `Equals`). Distinct ускорится ещё в 2-3 раза. Да и в принципе вы по умолчанию *должны* переопределять `GetHashCode`, если переопределяете `Equals`.

Comment: @MaxS Методика тестирования понятна, у меня пример просто демонстрационный. Потерялся сброс и пуск таймера перед последним тестом - не специально, честное слово.

Comment: @MaxS Без перезагрузки Equals и GetHashCode нельзя перезагрузить операции равенства и неравенства - знаете, наверно.

Comment: @rotabor Можно перегрузить операторы `==` и `!=` без перегрузки методов `Equals` и `GetHashCode`, всё скомпилируется. Но *не рекомендуется*. И как раз и из этого в том числе следует, что если вы перегружаете операторы равенства, то переопределите `Equals` с реализацией аналогичной логики сравнения, а не просто вызовите в нем реализацию базового класса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141468/discussion-between-rotabor-and-max-s).